# iBus (Anthy) not working with Skype 4.1.0.20

Tags: skype, ibus

I got Skype working with iBus (and it took a while at the time), but recently both my working set-up (on 12.04) broke, and any attempts for a new set-up (on 12.10) failed. (On 2 separate computers.)

That is to say, iBus does not input in the Skype window any longer. (iBus is running, and selecting the Anthy input method has no effect when the cursor is in the Skype window. It works fine via keyboard shortcut or the iBus menu in other applications.) I have the lines

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
export XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
export QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
export XIM_PROGRAM=/usr/bin/ibus-daemon
```

in my `.bashrc`. And have the qt & gtk versions of ibus installed. Has anything changed for Skype and iBus to stop working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the solution for this!

`/usr/bin/ibus-daemon` must be started with `-x` option.

I've added 'iBus' to startup applications with following command:

```
/usr/bin/ibus-daemon -x -d
```

I also have following lines in my `/etc/environment` but I'm not sure if they affect the result somehow (don't really want to experiment now):

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
```

Update: variables mentioned above has no any effect really in case of skype

Update 2: on Fresh installation of Ubuntu 12.10 I just installed ibus-qt4 (not ibus!) and selected iBus as IME. It works without any additional tricks

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me with mnemosyne (a Qt-application) and IBus was: 
Just change the Qt input method to XIM (I know you're using IBus, so do I.).

I don't know why this works but it was the only thing that worked for me. Adding system variables like QT_IM_MODULE=ibus etc in ~/.bashrc and ~/.xprofile only crashed my IBus instance so it didn't even work in Gtk-Apps.

You can change your this setting by running `qtconfig-qt4` (you have to install it first).

[ibus](/questions/tagged/ibus)[mnemosyne](/questions/tagged/mnemosyne)[qt](/questions/tagged/qt)